# Группировка по дате в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте. Имеется таблица с большим количеством записей. В ней поле datetime c типом `TIMESTAMP`.  Требуется группировка по датам. У меня появилось 3 варианта.

1. `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)`
2. `GROUP BY UNIX\_TIMESTAMP(datetime) - UNIX\_TIMESTAMP(datetime)%(60\*60\*24)` - отнимаем остаток от деления на день, то есть округляем до дня. Первый вариант работает ~2.1 сек, второй ~0.95.

Тогда я понял, что с целым типом мускулю легче работать, и добавил к таблице поле `unix\_datetime` с типом INT, и записал туда `UNIX\_TIMESTAMP(datetime)`, чтоб избавиться от преобразований.
И сделал 3-ю группировку: `GROUP BY unix\_datetime - unix\_datetime%(60\*60\*24)`
К моему удивлению, она работает за ~1.25 сек.
Индексы есть и на datetime и на unix_datetime.

Итого имеем результаты выполнения:

1. `GROUP BY DATE(datetime)`  - **~2.1** сек
2. `GROUP BY UNIX\_TIMESTAMP(datetime) - UNIX\_TIMESTAMP(datetime)%(60\*60\*24)`  - **~0.95** сек.
3. `GROUP BY unix\_datetime - unix\_datetime%(60\*60\*24)` - **~1.25** сек.

Кто-нибудь может объяснить, почему второй вариант работает быстрее 3-го? Может кто предложит еще варианты (группировать требуется не только по дате, но и по часам, неделям, месяцам). Просто тестил на группировке по дням.

Comment: @ray1992, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).@ray1992, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать, почему такая разница между `INT` и `TIMESTAMP` в пользу второго. По идее, все должно быть наоборот, потому как `TIMESTAMP` на низком уровне в MySQL хранится как целое число. Видимо, действительно что-то в алгоритмах...

Но одно абсолютно точно: индексы у вас хоть и имеются, но в этом запросе они не используются. Это потому, что вы используете не чистое значение, а выражение по нему. Для наиболее эффективного выполнения этого запроса стоит пойти на денормализацию. Добавить поле с типом `DATE`, заполнить и проиндексировать его, чтобы группировка выполнялась по полю без выражений.

Answer (score 0):

http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/

Первый раз затупил. Не то ответил.

По ссылке есть бенч на три типа данных: INT, TIMESTAMP, DATETIME. Есть один нюанс. INT, конечно, быстро обрабатыватся, но не в случае сравнений больше/меньше. Видимо, здесь все зависит от алгоритмов сравнения DATETIME и TIMESTAMP.