# среднее значение по дням

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица, в нее каждые две минуты пишет время и температуру.

```
 INSERT INTO `stats` (`stats_time`, `stats_t`) VALUES
(1450537200, 12),
(1450537320, 14),
(1450537440, 13);
```

avg выводит среднее значение в общем.
Вопрос: как вывести массив с средним значением по суткам за один месяц?

Comment: делаете `group by date(stats_time)`, а нужный месяц в условии пишите, например, через `WHERE stats_time >= LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH AND stats_time < LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY`

Comment: По поводу группировки по дням есть ссылка прям здесь на сайте - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/361368/%D0%93%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B2-mysql

Comment: А уж в списке полей выделите год, месяц и день из таймштампа

Comment: LAST_DAY и ваще я запутался с новыми для меня функциями, не поможете с составлением запроса? уж очень сложно для меня это, или я просто мало практикуюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

судя по приведённому вами оператору *insert*, время вы храните в столбце с числовым типом. первый мой пример — с таблицей *s1* — так и сделан.

но, возможно, неплохим выбором было бы использование [более подходящего типа данных](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html). как, например, во втором примере, с таблицей *s2*.

для работы с датой и временем есть [вполне достаточный набор встроенных функций](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), который можно использовать и для вашего запроса.

я привёл пример для отбора только за один день и с группировкой по часам (из-за скудности предоставленных вами данных). надеюсь, заменить функции и даты не составит большого труда.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20ec79/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table s1 (stime int, stemp int);

insert into s1 values
   (1450537200, 12)
  ,(1450537320, 14)
  ,(1450537440, 13)
;

create table s2 (stime datetime, stemp int);

insert into s2 values
   (from_unixtime(1450537200), 12)
  ,(from_unixtime(1450537320), 14)
  ,(from_unixtime(1450537440), 13)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select avg(stemp), hour(from_unixtime(stime))
from s1
where from_unixtime(stime) between '2015-12-19' and '2015-12-20'
group by hour(from_unixtime(stime))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20ec79/5/0)**:

```
| avg(stemp) | hour(from_unixtime(stime)) |
|------------|----------------------------|
|         13 |                         15 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select avg(stemp), hour(stime)
from s2
where stime between '2015-12-19' and '2015-12-20'
group by hour(stime)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/20ec79/5/1)**:

```
| avg(stemp) | hour(stime) |
|------------|-------------|
|         13 |          15 |
```